# If error; do something / if do Something else error

Tags: java, error-handling, exception

In our class I was told that there is a best practice to use condition like this:

```
if (a) { code } else { different code }
```

instead of

```
if (! a) { different code } else { code }
```

but in case of validating input I think that following example is not easily readable:

first example

```
if (something) {
    if (somethingElse) {
        doSomething
    } else {
        error message: somethingElse is wrong (different message)
        exit
    }
} else {
    error message: something is wrong
    exit
}
```

I think that this example is better (more readable) then building a pyramid of conditions:

second example

```
if (! something) {
    error message: something is wrong
    exit
}
if (! somethingElse) {
    error message: somethingElse is wrong (different message)
    exit
}

doSomething

exit
```

Would you choose first or second example?

Comment: This is pretty opinion-based.  But I do agree with you that the second example is cleaner.  And if you need to defend this to your teammates, it's worth pointing out that there's even a name for this exact pattern: https://refactoring.com/catalog/replaceNestedConditionalWithGuardClauses.html

Comment: Yes a personal preference. I prefer to divide according to the need, for validations as you mentioned and if my NOT condition throws an error, then I don't feel the need to wrap my complete positive flow in an If. Would rather have a NOT validation checked and error thrown at first itself. I think what was told to you is in a more generic sense, readable and in align with the way our normal thought process is.

Comment: It’s also worth noting that if the negative condition is “harder to read” then you can extract the condition itself into a well-named method.  If the code reads like semantically obvious prose, it doesn’t get easier to read than that.

Comment: You may find http://web.archive.org/web/20090308011225/https://www.perforce.com/perforce/papers/prettycode.html interesting, particularly the bits about early exits and controlling indentation. But generally, this is something people will have opinions about and fight unreasonably over, so I'll vote to close.

Comment: Thank you David, Novice and Arnt, this is very good answer. I'll also check refactoring.com and perforce.com. These looks very useful for a beginner.

Comment: You reinvented a design pattern known as guard clause. See for example https://refactoring.com/catalog/replaceNestedConditionalWithGuardClauses.html

Comment: See also http://wiki.c2.com/?GuardClause and http://wiki.c2.com/?HandleErrorsInContext

Comment: @arnt it may also be qualified as duplicate if one knows about guard clause, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4887212/shall-i-use-guard-clause-and-try-to-avoid-else-clause As you can see, this kind of question is not always closed even if somehow opinion based. Style matters and it's good to have rationale behind those opinions.

Comment: The first rule is not about the guard clause, but about having an `else` after an `if (!condition)`. When you do, you get a double negation for the `else` - "not not condition". Avoid that!